# Promise don't want to enter in then if form isn't sending two times

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, post, promise

I am working on a login page in Nodejs using Expressjs with a Neo4j DB.

I want to check with a function if a user already exists on my DB.
So I created a Models (MVC) which named Users and I declared a Class inside and also a method is isUserAlreadyExist.

My problem is that I am returning a promise from this method to handle it on my controller, but the then closure doesn't work I have to resend the form on the web page to have the result treated.

> Here is my controller code :

```
exports.postRegister = (req, res, next) => { //async
if(req.method == "POST")
{
    const login = req.body.login;
    const passwd = req.body.passwd;
    console.log('login = '+login +' passwd = '+passwd);
    if(login == null || passwd == null)
    {
        return res.status(400).send('Error: Params missings');
    }
    else {
        const new_user = new User(login, passwd);
        new_user.isUserAlreadyExist().then((result) =>{
            console.log(result)
        }).catch((err) =>{
            console.err(err);
        })
    }
}
```

}

> Here is a part of my Model User

```
    async isUserAlreadyExist()
{
    const session = db.session();
    const params = this.login;

    const cypher = "MATCH (a:User) WHERE a.login = {login} RETURN a";
    const params = {login : login};

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        session.run(cypher, params).then(result => {
            session.close()
            resolve(result.records.length);
        }).catch(err =>{
            session.close()
        })
    });
}
```

> As @robertklep and @solooo7 suggest , i make this changes but the situation is the same

```
isUserAlreadyExist()
{
    const session = db.session();
    const login = this.login;

    const cypher = "MATCH (a:User) WHERE a.login = {login} RETURN a";
    const params = {login : login};

    return (session.run(cypher, params)
    .then(result => {
        session.close();
        return result.records.length;
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        session.close();
        return (-1);
    })
}
```

Comment: Async function returns a promise. Why are you explicitly returning a promise?

Comment: Because first I was thinking that the problem was about returning the promise @soloo7

Comment: `session.run()` already returns a promise as well, so wrapping it with `new Promise` is superfluous. Also, if an error is caught, you're not calling `reject` so the promise is never settled.

Comment: I just updated the topic @robertklep but nothing change

Comment: Try this. https://bin.mkr.pw/~5d2b2491211a403ab3c0369c @saouas

Comment: I have tried but same issue @solooo7 :(

Comment: Can you give the error message?

Comment: Uh, your controller never sends a response in the `else` case where a new user is created?

Comment: @solooo7 There isn't error message , the page is still loading and the request take long time after ~ 3-4 minute the console.log appear in my server. If i want to see it now , i need to resend my form and the result appear for the last one

Comment: @Bergi not for the moment , but it didn't change the final result , if for example i decided to redirect to the home page. The probleme of form is still persisting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. The problem was that my function to treat the form (postRegister) was not asynchronous one and the function wasn't awaiting for mothing.

Here is the new code of my controller :

```
exports.postRegister = async (req, res, next) => { //async
    const login = req.body.login;
    const passwd = req.body.passwd;
    console.log('login = '+login +' passwd = '+passwd);
    if(login == null || passwd == null)
    {
        return res.status(400).send('Error: Params missings');
    }
    else {
        const new_user = new User(login, passwd);
        await new_user.isUserAlreadyExist().then((result) =>{
            console.log(result)
            res.redirect('/');
        }).catch((err) =>{
            console.err(err);
            res.redirect('/');
        })
    }
    console.log('end');
}
```

Thanks you for all people who helped me !